# Custom rules menu doesn't seem to be present

Tags: sonarqube

I am logged in as an administrator but I can't seem to find the menu to add new custom XPATH rules.

I'm following the steps from the link below :
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules

"Once your new rule is written, you can add it SonarQube:
     Login as an Quality profile administrator
     Go to Quality Profile
     Select one of the quality profiles for the language you wish to add the rule to
     Look for the XPath rule template:"

I'm using sonarqube server 4.4.1

This is my Rules Tab:

[image: Rules tab]

Where is it located in that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not up to date. Since SonarQube 4.4, custom rules are managed from the "Rules" space (directly accessible through the top navigation bar).

[image: Creating custom rules in SQ 4.4+]

Comment: I can't seem to find the add button add in that menu. 
Could you take a 1minute and take a screen shot of where it is suposed to be located.
That would be nice.

thanks

Comment: I added my rules tab in the original post

Comment: I found it. I had to search for "XPath" in the search bar and then i found the template. Do you know why my version doesn't have the template dropdown and the button "Create" next to new search?

Comment: My bad, the "Templates" dropdown and the "Create" button (for manual rules) were added in 4.5; but the "Create" button for custom rules is already there in 4.4