# Adding own rules for Java in SonarQube through XPath not working

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to add my new java related rules.
But on SonarQube GUI, I am not getting any option for the same.
I go to QualityProfiles->Java Profile->Sonar way.

It shows existing rules but nothing is there to add a new one..

Please help on this.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using? This changed a lot in recent versions.

Comment: I am using sonarqube-4.4.1. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SonarQube 4.4, custom rules are not managed through the Quality Profiles page, but rather through the Rules page. See [Custom rules menu doesn't seem to be present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163678/custom-rules-menu-doesnt-seem-to-be-present/26175149)